# giving a increment name to a text

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string newFile = textBox1.Text;
        string temp = newFile.Replace("YNATEST.", "");

        SaveFileDialog a1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        a1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\esra.ur\Desktop\projee1";
        a1.FileName = "";
        a1.Filter = "Text Files(*txt)|*.txt";
        a1.DefaultExt = "txt";
        a1.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "-1";
        a1.OverwritePrompt = false;
        a1.ShowDialog();
        StreamWriter yazmaislemi = new StreamWriter(a1.FileName);
        yazmaislemi.WriteLine(temp);
        yazmaislemi.Close();
}
```

`a1.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "-1";` with this part I take the system date to give a name to my text.`"-1"` means it is the first text in that folder. So my program should check other texts in `projee1` because it should take the latest one and add 1 to this after that give the name.
For example in the folder there are: `17/07/2015-1.txt` and `17/07/2015-2.txt` so the newest text should be 17/07/2015-3 
Do you have any idea to do this?

Comment: How about keep this as a numeric value and decrement your `-1` everytime by 1? With your code, it will never change.

Comment: Just enumerate the files of ``a1.InitialDirectory`` and search for the latest file. Also, put ``a1.ShowDialog();`` in an ``if``-branch, the user might cancel the saving process.

Comment: Should it just do this for the files you are saving at that moment. Or should it take the files already in the folder in account?

Comment: How can I check for the latest one?

Comment: what, if there are the files *17/07/2015-1.txt* and *17/07/2015-3*? Will the logic suggest *17/07/2015-2* or *17/07/2015-4*?

Comment: it should be in order so it is impossible to pass from 1 to 3

Comment: it isn't impossible, you have to deal with all cases.

Comment: take a look at http://pastebin.com/Fu5QSw5z